# How do I display resized images in tkinter using classes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display a resized image, but I'm not sure how to do that using classes. This code works fine:

```
image = Image.open(Image_Location)
image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

But I need to do this in a class method (because I need multiple for the main project and it would take too long to do it seperately), how do I do it? This is what I have tried so far:

```
class Planet:
    def __init__(self, name, picture):
        self.name = name
        self.picture = tk.PhotoImage(file=picture)

    @classmethod
    def resize_image(cls, picture):
        image = Image.open(picture)
        image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

earth = Planet("earth",Image_Location)
earth_resized = earth.resize_image(Image_Location)

test1 = Label(root, image=earth_resized)
test2 = Label(root, image=earth.picture)
test1.pack()
test2.pack()
```

And when I pack both labels, I get a white space (I think that is supposed to be the resized image) and the unsized image. Thanks!

Comment: Your classmethod does not return anything nor does it set anything - whatever work it does is forgotten. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the resized image from the method -- it should look like this:

```
    @classmethod
    def resize_image(cls, picture):
        image = Image.open(picture)
        image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```